# Script wont work when passed to wp_enqueue_script

Tags: wordpress

After realizing i need to use the wp_enqueue_script for any javascript on my website, I have begun trying to use the wp_enqueue_script and am getting no where.

my .php file contains:

```
<?php
function EnactScript(){
    wp_register_script('CommercePlugin', plugins_url('js/CouponGenerator.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('CommercePlugin');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'EnactScript');
function GenCoupon(){
echo "<input type = \"button\" onclick = \"randomCoupGen(); this.disabled = true\">Click here to see if you won!!</input>";
echo '<imgr src="' . plugins_url('js/CouponGenerator.js', __FILE__) . '" > ';
}
add_filter('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'GenCoupon', 9999999, 2);
?>
```

This it the CouponGenerator.js code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function randomCoupGen()
{
var RanNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
if(RanNum == 1)
{
alert("You rolled a 1");
}
else if(RanNum == 2)
{
alert("You rolled a 2.");
}
else
{
alert("You rolled something other than 1 or 2");
}
}
</script></head><body></body></html>
```

What do I need to do to make sure my JS is getting loaded when wp_head(); is called?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in the way you've enqueued the script. Make sure the JS file actually exists in the specified path.

Also you may need to remove the `<imgr>` tag, whatever it means.

Finally you don't need the HTML tags in the JS file. 
Your CouponGenerator.js code should be like this:

```
function randomCoupGen()
{
var RanNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
if(RanNum == 1)
{
alert("You rolled a 1");
}
else if(RanNum == 2)
{
alert("You rolled a 2.");
}
else
{
alert("You rolled something other than 1 or 2");
}
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly now. I guess taking away the script and html tags worked. Thank you so much.